# parse a string in javascript by a common delimiter

Tags: javascript, regex, string, parsing

In javascript I have a string of the form "/john/smith". I'd like to get the array "first-name" : "john", "last-name" : "smith".

Does js have some easy function to parse this string based on a seperator? I haven't seen any and google returned nothing except doing some regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var str="/john/smith"
var ar=str.split("/");
```

now **ar[1]** will contain **firstname**

& **ar[2]** will contain **lastname**

Answer (score 2):

You can use the .split() method for this.  See the MDN for a reference on .split(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

It's very simple to use.

```
var namestring = "/John/Smith";
var pieces = namestring.split("/");
```

pieces[1] contains "John" and pieces[2] contains "Smith".  Note that those index arrays are 1 and 2, not 0 and 1.  pieces[0] contains "" because split() returns the strings separated by the supplied delimiter.  There's an empty string before the first "/" character, so the first result is empty.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?:

```
var str = "/john/smith";

//empty is here because if you split by / you'll get ["", "john", "smith"]
var getObject = function(empty, first, last) {
    //You could traverse arguments, witch will have every match in an "array"
    return {
       first_name: first,
       last_name: last
    };
}

firstAndLastName = getObject.apply(null, str.split('/')); //Object {first_name: "john", last_name: "smith"}
```

Answer (score 0):

`split()` method will do the trick

```
var str="/john/smith"
var arr=str.split("/");
```

arr[1] will give forstname and arr[2] will give secondname

Answer (score 0):

A few ways to do this for your particular example, given that most other answers will leave a `/` at the beginning these will output the correct result:

```
var result = str.match(/[^/]+/g);
```

Or:

```
var result = str.split('/').slice(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple Javascript [*split*](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) method should work.

```
var myOriginalString = '/John/Smith';
var afterSplitArray = myOriginalString.split('/');
var firstName = afterSplitArray[1]; // John
var lastName = afterSplitArray[2]; //Smith
```

The only catch being, if your original string starts with the delimiter, you've to start accessing variables from index = 1, as in the above example.